# Displaying Table view dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have stuck with an issue of  displaying data with appropriate format. Please guide me how to achieve of expected result in jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
      var numbers = ['hamburger', 'Potato salad', 'Brocolli', 'Apple pie'];
      var month = [2,3,6,5,4];
    for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
    console.log(numbers[i]);
    $('#foodItem').append(numbers[i]);
    $('#portionSize').append(month[i]);
    }
});
</script>
```

**html**

```
<table> <tr>
        th>Food Item</th>
        <th>Portion Size</th>           
         </tr>          
         <td id="foodItem">             
         </td>          
         <td id="portionSize">          
         </td></table>
```

**Output**

```
FoodItem                                 Portion size
hamburgerPotatosaladBrocolliApple         2365
```

**Expected Output**

```
 FoodItem             Portion Size
  hamburger                2
  potato salad             3
  Brocolli                 6
  Apple                    5
```

Comment: Hey @Giridharan it might be you just missed starting tag for <th> Food Item</th>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new tr when adding data to your table. This can be done like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var food = ['hamburger', 'Potato salad', 'Brocolli', 'Apple pie'];
  var portion = [2, 3, 6, 5];
  for (i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
    $('#myTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + food[i] + '</td><td>' + portion[i] + '</td></tr>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Food Item</th>
      <th>Portion Size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: :But it produces 3 <td> tag. I need only two <td> tag. On running your code am getting for ex: <tr><td>apple pie</td><td></td><td>5</td>

Comment: @Giridharan my bad. Missed a closing tag. Should be working now

Answer (score 2):

My proposal is:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var numbers = ['hamburger', 'Potato salad', 'Brocolli', 'Apple pie'];
  var month = [2, 3, 6, 5, 4];
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    $('<tr>').append($('<td>').append(numbers[i]))
    .append($('<td>').append(month[i]))
    .appendTo('table tbody');
  }
});
```

```css
td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1) {
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
}
td:nth-child(2), td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Food Item</th>
        <th>Portion Size</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: just apply css to show portion size for showing text-align middle will look awesome isn't it .?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var numbers = ['hamburger', 'Potato salad', 'Brocolli', 'Apple pie'];
    var month = [2,3,6,5,4];

    for(var i=0; i<numbers.length;i++) {

        $("table").append("<tr><td id=foodItem>" + numbers[i] + "</td><td id=portionSize>" + month[i] + "</td></tr>")


    }

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        
        <table border="1">
            <tr><th>Food Item</th><th>Portion Size</th></tr>       
        </table>
        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var numbers = ['hamburger', 'Potato salad', 'Brocolli', 'Apple pie'];
        var month = [2,3,6,5,4];

        for(var i=0; i<numbers.length;i++) {

            $("table").append("<tr><td id=foodItem>" + numbers[i] + "</td><td id=portionSize>" + month[i] + "</td></tr>")


        }

    })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var numbers  = ['hamburger', 'Potato salad', 'Brocolli', 'Apple pie'];
  var month  = [2, 3, 6, 5];
  var newtr = '';
  for (i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
      newtr += '<tr>';
      newtr += '<td>'+ numbers[i] + '</td>';
      newtr += '<td>'+ month[i] + '</td>';
      newtr += '</tr>';
    }
  $('#Order').append(newtr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Order">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Food Item</th>
      <th>Portion Size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please Modify  js and html like bellow

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var numbers = ['hamburger', 'Potato salad', 'Brocolli', 'Apple pie'];
  var month = [2, 3, 6, 5, 4];
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     table.append('<tr><td>' + numbers[i] + '</td><td>' + month[i]);
  }
});
```

Html:

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Food Item</th>
    <th>Portion Size</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```